# Why is A.issuperset(B) much slower than all(b in A for b in B)?

Tags: python, performance, set, python-internals

Consider testing whether a set `A` is a superset of an iterable `B`, once with the set's method for exactly that, and once with my own expression using the definition of superset:

```
>>> A = set(range(1000))
>>> B = range(-1000, 0)
>>> A.issuperset(B)
False
>>> all(b in A for b in B)
False
```

Now let's time that:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit(lambda: A.issuperset(B))
52.666367300000005
>>> timeit(lambda: all(b in A for b in B))
0.9698789999999917
```

The set's own method is much slower. Why? Presumably it can/should do the same thing, but at C speed, so should be *faster*.

I'm using CPython 3.8.1.

Comment: `issuperset` short-circuits, too, see implementation here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f9bd05e83e32bece49de5af0c9a232325c57648a/Objects/setobject.c#L1692

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.1/Objects/setobject.c#L1748-L1795) of `set.issubset` and `set.issuperset` insists on building a set out of the argument first:

```
static PyObject *
set_issubset(PySetObject *so, PyObject *other)
{
    setentry *entry;
    Py_ssize_t pos = 0;
    int rv;

    if (!PyAnySet_Check(other)) {
        PyObject *tmp, *result;
        tmp = make_new_set(&PySet_Type, other);
        if (tmp == NULL)
            return NULL;
        result = set_issubset(so, tmp);
        Py_DECREF(tmp);
        return result;
    }
    if (PySet_GET_SIZE(so) > PySet_GET_SIZE(other))
        Py_RETURN_FALSE;

    while (set_next(so, &pos, &entry)) {
        rv = set_contains_entry((PySetObject *)other, entry->key, entry->hash);
        if (rv < 0)
            return NULL;
        if (!rv)
            Py_RETURN_FALSE;
    }
    Py_RETURN_TRUE;
}

PyDoc_STRVAR(issubset_doc, "Report whether another set contains this set.");

static PyObject *
set_issuperset(PySetObject *so, PyObject *other)
{
    PyObject *tmp, *result;

    if (!PyAnySet_Check(other)) {
        tmp = make_new_set(&PySet_Type, other);
        if (tmp == NULL)
            return NULL;
        result = set_issuperset(so, tmp);
        Py_DECREF(tmp);
        return result;
    }
    return set_issubset((PySetObject *)other, (PyObject *)so);
}

PyDoc_STRVAR(issuperset_doc, "Report whether this set contains another set.");
```

`issuperset` makes a set out of the argument, then calls `other.issubset(self)`. (`issubset` also insists on having a set as its argument, but it gets one, so it doesn't need to convert in this case.) They could have fairly easily added a code path to `issuperset` to handle non-set arguments without a set conversion, but they didn't.

I suspect the reason for this may be to throw an error on calls like `{1}.issuperset([2, [3]])`, where the argument contains unhashable elements. However, it's also likely that no one bothered to optimize it. Searching the [Python issue tracker](https://bugs.python.org/) for `issuperset` turns up 0 issues about optimizing `issuperset`, not even closed issues. There's a [closed issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue18032) about a *more* difficult optimization for `issubset`, surprisingly, but while it would have caused similar exception behavior changes, none of the replies on the issue said anything about that.

Comment: About that possible reason: Maybe, although the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issuperset) just says "Test whether every element in *other* is in the set" and that *other* can be "any iterable", I don't see anything about hashable elements.

Comment: That `issubset` optimization seems not just more difficult but also less space-efficient, keeping track of the set's elements already encountered in the iterable. For `issuperset` that wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I think we can rule that hashability reason out, since the related `{1}.isdisjoint([1, [2]])` doesn't complain and just returns `False`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the difference comes from the fact that in your test, you don't actually run `issuperset` between two sets, but rather between a set and a range. Much of the time is spent on converting the range to a set. Consider the following timings:

```
A = set(range(1000))
B_set = set(range(-1000, 0))
B_range = range(-1000, 0)
B_list = list(range(-1000, 0))

%%timeit 
A.issuperset(B_set)
654 ns ± 6.09 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%%timeit 
A.issuperset(B_range)
29.9 µs ± 259 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%%timeit 
A.issuperset(B_list)
15.4 µs ± 233 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)


# Creating a set from a range. 
%%timeit
B_set = set(B_range)
29.2 µs ± 209 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%%timeit 
all(b in A for b in B_set)
816 ns ± 16.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%%timeit 
all(b in A for b in B_range)
474 ns ± 4.74 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```